# How to create a square wave signal with 120MHz

Tags: frequency, generator, wave

What is a cheap way to generate a square wave with a frequency of 120MHz. I've been thinking of the following solutions:

- Use a Raspberry Pi, then use a timer or something from that board
- Use an oscillator (will the signal be a square wave or sinusoidal?)
- Use an oscillator + PLL
- Use an FPGA/CPLD

I like the oscillator (e.g. http://at.farnell.com/saronix/s1903c-120-00-e/quarzoszillator-smd-120-000000mhz/dp/1210018) approach very much, but I couldn't find out if the output signal will be a square wave or sinusoidal.

I need the signal to feed it into a SerDes part and then do some tests with that part.

Any ideas?

Maybe I should add that the device will not be directly placed near the IC, therefore the signal should have some "power" on its output line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a [Schmitt trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) to get a square wave from a sine.

Comment: explaining more will be great =)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, just checked what parts we have in stock and I could find a 24MHz Oscillator and a configurable frequency multiplier. The result ist not really a square wave but it should be ok.

Comment: If you want a better square wave, multiply the 24 MHz by 10 and then divide by 2. Dividing by 2 produces a good square wave with equal high and low duration.